# Issues when sharing screen using Vidyo Screen Share Chrome extension on Vidyo.io

Tags: vidyo

I'm using vidyo.io as videoconference solution in our platform. I'm having an issue with Vidyo's Chrome extension for screen sharing that is easily reproducible using the very own Vidyo's samples:

If you download Vidyo's web sample from developer portal, open `samples/VidyoConnector/js/VidyoConnector.html` in Chrome, choose 'Join via the browser', and click the 'Window share' select list (there is no need to start a conference to reproduce the error), Chrome will open the Vidyo Screen Share extension page *twice*, **even if you already have the plugin installed**. For this to work you have to uninstall the extension and reinstall it again. It will work until the end of the current session.

In the other hand if you go to Vidyo.io developer portal, choose "Demo" from "Developers" menu and start a conference using the "Join via the browser" button, click the same 'Window share' select list the Vidyo Screen Share extension works as expected, allowing you to pick a window or a screen to share.

In our implementation we're having the same problem as the code from web sample listed above, but if an example of our code would be of any help to clarify the issue, here you have an excerpt (we're using Angular, and here you have some TypeScript code):

```
private vidyoConnector: VidyoClientLib.VidyoClient.VidyoConnector;

(...)

selectedWindowShare(share: VidyoClientLib.VidyoClient.VidyoLocalWindowShare) {
  this.vidyoConnector.SelectLocalWindowShare({localWindowShare: share})
}
```

This issue happens only on Chrome. When we use Firefox it works seamlessly. I'm using Chrome 69 on OSX High Sierra.

Any suggestion on how to solve this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are either running the VidyoConnector.html directly in the browser or hosting the sample on non-secured hosting (HTTP).
For the Vidyo Screen Share Chrome extension to work correctly, you need to host it on a secured hosting (HTTPS).
You can verify this by using our hosted sample here:
https://static.vidyo.io/latest/connector/VidyoConnector.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Running our app under https worked also. Thanks!